# General solution for Parametric amplification in harmonic oscillator

Tags: harmonic-oscillator, resonance

It is well known that for the simple harmonic oscillator of the form

$$
\frac{d^{2}x}{dt^{2}} = -\omega_{s}^{2}x
$$
where $\omega_{s}$ is the resonant frequency of the oscillation, has the general solution
$$
x(t) = x_{0}\text{cos}(\omega_{s}t) + \frac{v_{0}}{\omega_{s}}\text{sin}(\omega_{s}t)
$$

Suppose now I modulate my resonant frequency periodically about some frequency $\omega_{0}$ with a pump frequency $\omega_{p}$, such that $\omega_{s}=\omega_{s}(t)=\omega_{0} + \delta\omega\text{sin}(\omega_pt)$, where we assume that $\delta\omega\ll\omega_{0}$, how do I find the general solution of $x(t)$ for $\omega_p = 2\omega_{s}$?

**Attempt:**
Here  is my initial attempt at the problem. I first substitute the time-dependent $\omega_{s}$ back into the first equation, such that
$$
\frac{d^{2}x}{dt^{2}} = -\omega_{s}^{2}(t)x \approx -\omega_{0}^{2}\Big(1 + 2\frac{\delta_{\omega}}{\omega_{0}}\text{sin}(\omega_{p}t)\Big)x
$$
where I have neglected terms which are quadratic in $\delta\omega$ (since $\delta\omega^{2}\ll1$). I am unsure of how to proceed from here to solve the preceding equation. I tried guessing an ansatz solution of the form
$$
x(t) = x_{0}e^{\lambda t}\text{cos}(\omega_{s}t)
$$
for some constant $\lambda$ (probably a function of $\delta\omega$), but substituting the ansatz solution back into the modified differential equation shows that it is not a valid solution (or I've made a mistake that I couldn't find). I do know that the solution must have some exponential dependence that shows that the $x(t)$ grows over time, signifying amplification. In general, how can I solve this problem and what should be the correct approach here?

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathieu_function

Comment: @hyportnex Thank you very much for your response. I took a look at it and noticed that what I have is indeed a Mathieu function, but what I should infer from the page and if there is anything on there that is helpful?

Comment: The Mathieu functions are the solutions of your equation, and if that is what you are interested in, then study them. I have only given you a general reference to start, but there are also many references on the bottom of the page. If you are worried about $\delta \omega$ not being sufficiently small then here is something else, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_differential_equation, this has been a very well studied subject for some 200 years now.

Answer (score 0):

The usual approach for getting the exponential growth is to use the Floquet method. You calculate the eigenvalues of the linear flow in the 2D phase space $(x,y)=(x,\dot x)$ after a period. In your case, you cannot compute it exactly unless you introduce Matthieu functions. You'll need to calculate the eigenvalues perturbatively in the limit $\delta\omega/\omega_0\ll 1$.

Note that you can do this exactly in the case when $\omega_s^2$ is a square wave. It turns out that the qualitative behaviour is the same. You can find more details in V. Arnold's *Ordinary Differential Equations*.

Btw, if you're familiar with quantum mechanics, this is the same approach as for Bloch waves in a periodic potential. The time is replaced by space and you reinterpret the equation of motion as a Schrödinger equation, with $\omega_s^2$ the periodic potential. Your parametric resonances correspond to the regions where there is a gap in the spectrum as the wave function cannot have an exponential growth.

Hope this helps.